# Fragment lifecycle events in LifeCycleAware Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, fragment-lifecycle

I have a lifecycle aware fragment and a `LifecycleObserver` class

```
        public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
            @Override
            public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                new MyObserver(this);

            }

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
            }
        }
```

Following is my Observer class where it logs all the fragment events propery

```
        public class MyObserver implements LifecycleObserver {
            private static final String TAG = "MyObserver";
            public MyObserver(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner) {
                lifecycleOwner.getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
            }

            @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
            public void onCreate(){
                Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");
            }

            @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE)
            public void onPause(){
                Log.d(TAG, "onPause: ");
            }

            @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
            public void onDestroy(){
                Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
            }

            @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
            public void onStart(){
                Log.d(TAG, "onStart: ");
            }

        }
```

I want to listen to fragment specific lifecycle events like `onDestroyView` and  `onActivityCreated` but these events are not there in

`Lifecycle.Event`. It contains only activity events. How can I listen for fragment events in my observer

Comment: Were you able to find anything about this?

Comment: I am also trying to figure this out. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Any way to achieve this using a lifecycle observer? The answers below can be implemented without lifecycle observer by writing our own custom methods and calling from fragments.

Answer (score 16):

You can observe the fragment's `viewLifecycleOwner` lifecycle.

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(yourObserverHere)
```

Then the fragment's `onDestroyView` lifecyle method is tied to the `@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)` annotated method.

Note that the fragment's `viewLifecycleOwner` is only available between `onCreateView` and `onDestroyView` lifecycle methods.

Comment: @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY) called when the fragment is destroyed not in destroyview

Comment: @Shalan93 it depends on which lifecycle, the fragment lifecycle or the fragment's view lifecycle.

Comment: Needs clarification

Comment: @Shalan93 Please read about `getViewLifecycleOwner()` method and you will understand it.

Comment: @Shalan93 check my answer for more details regarding `ON_DESTROY `

Answer (score 1):

Just a supplement to Basim Alamuddin's answer：

As you can see in the resource codes, `@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)` is also called when you add an observer to `viewLifecycleOwner`:     viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(this)

```
// androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

void performDestroyView() {
    if (mView != null) {
        mViewLifecycleOwner.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY);
    }
    onDestroyView();

void performDestroy() {
    mLifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY);
    onDestroy();
```

Answer (score -5):

Well, according to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html?hl=id), literally `onDestroyView` will be called after `onStop`. So, If you need the logic to run before onDestroyView or detecting it, i think it's is best to call it or detect in the fragment's onStop() method. In your case, i think you need to implement `Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP` & `Lifecycle.Event.ON_START` for `onActivityCreated`.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle

Answer (score -6):

[Fragment Life Cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle)

```
onCreateView()
```

Called to create the view hierarchy associated with the fragment.

```
onDestroyView()
```

Called when the view hierarchy associated with the fragment is being removed.

Comment: My question is about [Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html#lc)