# Android kotlin - how to create a property delegate for toolbar backbutton press

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a fragment that has a toolbar and i currently set the back button listen like this:

```
 with(myToolBarView) {
            (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(this)
            setNavigationOnClickListener {
                requireActivity().onBackPressed()
            }
        }
```

but when i have other fragments this code gets repeated all the time. so i wish i could do something like this:
myToolBarView by backButtonDelegate(this)

but the problem is for one, the view wont be ready until after onCreateView gets called. So i'll get null or some exception if i try to access the view before its ready. so then how i can do this?

i tried using  **@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)** but i don't see how that will help me and also i need code called every time onoCreateView is called incase the fragment view is re-created.

update: i now [realize the lifecycleowner of a fragment works with the fragment view lifecycle][1]

so here is what i have so far:

```
 class BackBtnDelegate(val fragment: Fragment) {

//    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): String {
//        return "$thisRef, thank you for delegating '${property.name}' to me!"
//    }

    init {
        fragment.lifecycle.addObserver(object : LifecycleObserver {
            @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
            fun onDestroy() {
                with(myToolBarView) { 
                    (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(this)
                    setNavigationOnClickListener {
                        requireActivity().onBackPressed()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }

//    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
//       // println("$value has been assigned to '${property.name}' in $thisRef.")
//    }
```

notice i dont even need the set or get propertty values here as they become meaningless and still i dont have a reference to myToolBarView  so how can i accomplish this ?
[1]: [Fragment lifecycle events in LifeCycleAware Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47091794/fragment-lifecycle-events-in-lifecycleaware-fragment)

Answer (score 1):

That is not how the [Delegation pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) works. Quote:

> In delegation, two objects are involved in handling a request: a receiving object delegates operations to its delegate

You could create an extension function for the `Fragment` class:

```kotlin
fun Fragment.setToolbar(myToolbar: Toolbar) {
    with(myToolbar) {
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(this)
    setNavigationOnClickListener {
        requireActivity().onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Or you could have common functions in a `BaseFragment` and have other Fragments implement that class, but I suppose you already know that.

```kotlin
class BaseFragment : Fragment() {
   ...

    protected fun setToolbar(myToolbar: Toolbar) {
        with(myToolbar) {
            (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(this)
            setNavigationOnClickListener {
                requireActivity().onBackPressed()
            }
        }
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes can do it from a  base class but trying to avoid that for composition at this point. Delegates is what i was hoping for. Extension not a bad idea